# Cascading dropdown with repeating table for SharePoint lists

Tags: 2013, custom-list, dropdown, cascading, datatable

I want Cascading dropdown with repeating table for SharePoint lists only by using SharePoint 2013 not with InfoPath. I have attached image what I require with only SharePoint 2013 not with InfoPath.

[image: what I exactly want only using by Share point 2013]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to achieve your scenario without using InfoPath  , I tried to simulate this without using InfoPath and this the output that I hope to match with you

[image]

**Steps:**

- Edit new page > Add your shoe models list.
- Click on arrow Shoe models > select connections > `Get Filter values from` > configure connection.
- Hide save and cancel with `display: none;`

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but it won't work for me. Now i want to bind 3 dropdown 1 for"Country" 2 for "State" 3 for"City" as i want to bind 2nd and 3rd dropdown according to 1st dropdown value.. without using Designer and InfoPath only by using Sharepoint online..

Comment: what's the issue , i apply it in my environment as shown in my screen shot

Comment: Thanks for your replay but .Now i want to add 3 dropdowns in which value of 2nd snd 3rd dropdown is depend on the selected value of 1st dropdown..like we select Country in 1st dropdown  and in 2nd and 3rd dropdown we get the related states and city..with using Sharepoint Online only not with Infopath and Sharepoint Designer..